# jQuery animate border pushing elements around. How to stop it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small jQuery based script for animating the border on images that you hover upon.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".oa-article a img").mouseover(function(e)
    {
        $(this).css('border-style', 'solid');
        $(this).css('border-color', '#C63');
        $(this).animate(
        {
            borderWidth: "5px",
        }, 100, function() 
        {
            // Animation complete.
        });
});


$(".oa-article a img").mouseleave(function(e)
    {
        $(this).animate(
        {
            borderWidth: "0px"
        }, 200, function() 
        {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });

});
```

The problem is; when that border is animated to 5px, it (obviously) adds those pixels to the width and height, and that results in some unwanted repositioning of other image links next to it (it's a gallery that has 4 images in a row, and so on).

I tried to absolute position them, but that borked the parent/child behavoiur thus making the page not grow from the images. The thing is though, the absolute positioning made it work like I wanted to. The border grew and did not affect any of the other image positions. That is what I want: When the border grows from 0 to 5 px, I don't wan't anything else to be affected by this in any way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`box-sizing: border-box` makes for the border to be included in the width/height (so that adding a border doesn't make the element grow): http://jsfiddle.net/8GdZy/1/.

```
img {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}​
```

The image itself is then shrinked.

Comment: Worked magnificently! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could give the images a border the same colour as the background to start with (assuming you have a solid colour background) then just animate border-color.

This would simplify your function slightly and remove the need to add magins or padding on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You could animate it to a negative margin :
as border goes from 0 to 5px, have margin go from 0 to -5px

Comment: Or have padding set to 5 and animate it to 0.

Comment: I tried that actually. Didnt work out quite well =P Not smooth either